# Do you need to rinse liver?

Tags: boiling, liver

I got into an argument about liver when I saw someone boil a tub of chicken livers by pouring the entire contents of the tub (blood) into a pot without rinsing the liver.  I always though that the rinse was required for health reasons (and to also improve the flavor.)  The other person insisted that she preferred the flavor of liver when it is prepared in this manner.  I think she may be getting defensive about her cooking methods, but is this a safe practice?  Is rinsing required or just preferred?

I like my liver rinsed, but is there anything unhealthy that could make me sick if I just dump the tub (straight from the store) into the pan an cook it all (this is how my girl friend insists on cooking liver.)

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak to health reasons (and we don't answer health related questions on SA) but, as for taste, rinsing chicken livers can be quite important.

I always rinse and check the chicken livers well to be sure that there are no gallbladders (or pieces) left attached to the liver. The gallbladder contains bile and even a small piece can ruin the taste of the whole pot. Please see  [this](https://www.cookipedia.co.uk/recipes_wiki/Liver) .